# Getting z-index to work: element disapears when being dragged

Tags: css, google-chrome, z-index

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/ghj1d7sf/1/) that I've made of a chess board using unicode characters.
My problem is when I drag a piece, it disappears even though I have a z-index of 1.

```
.player {
    z-index:1;
    cursor:pointer;
}
main {
    font-size:25px;
}
.boardRow {
    border-left:3px solid #000;
    clear:left;
}
.top {
    border-top:1px solid #000;
}
.cell {
    z-index:0;
    float:left;
    width:3em;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    /* Doesn't work */
}
.first {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
}
```

And here's the html:

```
<main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="boardRow">
        <span class="top cell first"><span class="player">&#9820;</span></span>
        <span class="top cell"><span class="player">&#9822;</span></span>
        <span class="top cell"><span class="player">&#9821;</span></span>
        <span class="top cell"><span class="player">&#9819;</span></span>
        <span class="top cell"><span class="player">&#9818;</span></span>
        <span class="top cell"><span class="player">&#9821;</span></span>
        <span class="top cell"><span class="player">&#9822;</span></span>
        <span class="top cell"><span class="player">&#9820;</span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="boardRow">
        <span class="cell first"><span class="player">&#9823;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9823;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9823;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9823;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9823;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9823;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9823;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9823;</span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="boardRow">
        <span class="cell first">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="boardRow">
        <span class="cell first">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="boardRow">
        <span class="cell first">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="boardRow">
        <span class="cell first">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
         <span class="cell">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="boardRow">
        <span class="cell first"><span class="player">&#9817;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9817;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9817;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9817;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9817;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9817;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9817;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9817;</span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="boardRow"> 
        <span class="cell first"><span class="player">&#9814;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9816;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9815;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9813;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9812;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9815;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9816;</span></span>
        <span class="cell"><span class="player">&#9814;</span></span>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and FF.

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm using Chrome beta...

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it on Mac/Safari and it worked.  Safari 7.0.5

Comment: If you are using Chrome Beta are you on a Linux OS of some sort?

Comment: Version 37.0.2062.68 beta-m (64-bit) Windows 7

Comment: Working on Chrome version 36.0.1985.125 m. Windows 8.1.

Comment: I tried it on Windows 7 (64-bit) Chrome version 36.0 and everything worked fine with the z-index.  You may want to take a look at the styles between Safari and Chrome because on my Windows machine the chess board was a square, but on my mac machine the styles for the chess board were not square at all.  That could have something to do with it.

Comment: z-index requires at least a `position: relative:` to work correctly...

Comment: I tried it in incognito mode (I think that removes all my extensions) and the piece still disappears as you drag it.

Comment: I might be wrong, but `z-index` usually expects for a defined position. (ie: `position: relative`).

Comment: It also works for me, across all updated, stable release browsers.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll test in another browser.  Thanks you guys.[Update with position:relative](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/ghj1d7sf/3/)